# Why was my account suspended 2 times?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I have my account in Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/users/2909797/monika

But one moderator [**Andrew Barber**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/) suspending my accounts 2 times. I like this site so much. But I am not getting the real reason for this. I analyzed that this moderator **Andrew Barber** also puts most of users' questions and answers on hold. Please look into my request other moderators. I want to know real reason behind my account suspension.

Comment: I'm willing to bet an expensive import beer that you were provided with exhaustive warnings and explanations prior to each suspension. And yes, Andrew Barber puts a lot of things on hold because that's kinda his job. (Either way, your question is in the right place here, we'll see what comes up.)

Comment: You know the answer to your question. It is in the message(s) you have gotten from moderators each time. Plus those when you weren't suspended. You have simply ignored the warnings entirely. Which I guess might explain this question, after all...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more of a rant than anything constructive.

Comment: I belive u monika,since from u find bug in  one of my code block. Its ok to learn and express coding style :-)

Comment: In one word: [Plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism).

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Please read the answers below, which explain the reason for the suspensions. Monika *does* post some really good answers, but a large number of them have been plagiarized, and they have not heeded *numerous* warnings about it.

Comment: @Festivus Unicorn So whats wronge in coping and pasting code from msdn? If person who post stupid question without googling then u must delete that question not suggested answer since we do something for explaing answer, also every developer learn programming concept from msdn only no one has theire own concept,right?

Comment: You are  right @AnkushMadankar

Answer (score 24):

> Why my account suspened 2 times?

Seriously?

Because of blatant, continued plagiarism. As the "suspended" message says in your profile. Plagiarism is wildly copy & pasting stuff you didn't write and pasting it into answers. That's not acceptable on Stack Overflow, nor anywhere else really.

Just checking your first 8 highest-voted answers:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626460/how-to-clear-objects-in-c-net/20626481#20626481) stolen 100% from [this MSDN answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/dfd6da0b-10b1-4a67-bde4-ac1410f88978/how-to-destroy-an-object-in-c?forum=csharplanguage) (10k+ rep only)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20234135/187606) stolen 100% from [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?474820-Replacing-strings-in-text-files-with-C) (10k+ rep only)
- Oh wow, an  [original contribution!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213270/how-do-i-remove-all-white-spaces-from-a-string/20213310#20213310)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20264415/187606) from [this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (10k+ rep only)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258336/convert-utc-datetime-to-local-timezone-in-xaml/20258376#20258376) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16921974/187606) (10k+ rep only)
- OK, actually attributed a source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20185940/187606) (but it's still not really an answer)

... and apparently, many many more that moderators have already deleted.

Answer (score 22):

You've been contacted by moderators a dizzying ***five*** times about your posts, and (as you note) suspended twice. Prior to going on a rant about the moderator, had you considered ***reading the messages that were sent to you describing the problem***?

If you can't find those messages (you get copied via email as well), [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and we'll make sure you get a copy. If you're having difficulty understanding what the moderators have been trying to tell you, contact us, we'll do our best to explain it.

Barring that, I'm considering this matter closed.